# What does convergence to equilibrium for the Fokker-Planck equation mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am a math major who recently started to study thermodynamics seriously. I have some confusing points while studying it, so I'd appreciate it if you'd correct me and give me some answers.

(1) As far as I know, a small particle immersed in a fluid is in Brownian motion, which takes place in **thermal equilibrium** (if the temperature is maintained constant).

(2) The special Fokker-Plank equation describes this Brownian motion. 
(For example, one dimensional Fokker-Plank equation is $\frac{\partial W}{\partial t} = \gamma \frac{\partial (vW)}{\partial v} + \gamma \frac{kT}{m}\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial v^2}$, where $W(v,t)$ is the distribution for the particle.)

However, the solution of the (general) Fokker-Planck equation $W(v,t)$ is not **in equilibrium**? If so, what sense of equilibrium is this?

(3) I've seen the phrase "**convergence to equilibrium**" in the literature about the Fokker-Planck equation. Here, even though $W(v,t)$ is not in equilibrium, it converges to equilibrium?

I am confused about the terminology 'equilibrium' here. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stationary solution of your Fokker-Planck equation is an equilibrium distribution.
 Here, assuming that $v$ is the variable for the velocity, that mean a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

So if your initial condition for the distribution $W(v,t)$ is not an equilibrium distribution, your system will not be at equilibrium. However the evolution of your distribution via the Fokker-Planck equation will brings it towards an equilibrium distribution, hence the convergence towards the equilibrium.

Fokker-Planck equation that do not contain non-conservative forces are also called equilibrium Fokker-Planck equation, as theirs stationary solution are equilibrium distribution, and the evolution is a relaxation towards an equilibrium distribution.